# How to reuse an open editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After opening an editor, for example like so:

```java
IEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput( ... );
IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = activePage.openEditor( input, "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor" );
```

I would like to reuse the returned `editor` with a different editor input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an editor to be reused, it must implement the `IReusableEditor` interface. If this is the case, the editor can be supplied with a new editor input through the workbench page it was opened in.

```java
IEditorInput editorInput = ...
IReusableEditor reusableEditor = ( IReusableEditor )editor;
reusableEditor.getSite().getPage().reuseEditor( reusableEditor, editorInput );
```